# Log Beta Distribution Priors

Tags: distributions, bayesian, prior, beta-distribution, beta-binomial-distribution

Let $X_n$ be a binomial distribution with parameter $\theta$. Empirically, after $n$ throws, my estimate is $\hat{\theta}_n=\frac{S_n}{S_n+F_n}$, where $S/F$ are the successes and failures $(F_n:=n-S_n)$.

From simulations on my dataset, I've found out that $-\log(\theta)$ is better approximated by a beta distribution, as opposed to the usual way of assuming $\theta$ has beta binomial prior $\mbox{Beta}(a+S_i,b+n-S_i)$. In other words, let $\phi_n:=\frac{-\log(\theta_n)-c}{d}$, ($c,d$ are shift/scaling constants) so that $\phi_n$ is assumed to have empirical distribution $\mbox{Beta}(a,b)$. Here's a qq-plot comparison, with $\theta$ assumed to be beta in the first image, and $-\log(\theta)$ assumed to be beta in the second:

[image: Theta Assumed to be Beta]

[image: -Log(Theta) Assumed to be Beta]

> **Question 1**: Are there any good examples of real-life situations where
>   the success probability is log-beta distributed? The literature search
>   on this is extremely annoying because it seems like people call it
>   either log-beta or exp-beta (I'm following the log-normal convention).
>
> **Question 2**: Is there any way of easily calculating the posterior
>   update for the log-beta distribution, based solely on $S_n$ and
>   $F_n$?. $\log(\theta_n)=\log(S_n)-\log(S_n+F_n)$, but this no longer
>   has the interpretation of success/failure. The integral looks to be a sum of confluent hypergeometric functions

Comment: I am curious how your dataset can indicate what the prior distribution ought to be.  Could you explain?

Comment: @whuber: I'm taking it as only empirical evidence. It also does a better job than a few other families that I've tried. That's why I'm interested in Question 1, because it would be compelling to at least see this happening elsewhere or have an example of a probabilistic process that gives rise to a log beta distribution.

Comment: But how do you obtain an empirical distribution for $\theta$?  Are you performing this estimate repeatedly in many similar circumstances?

Comment: @whuber: Right, I have a large dataset of triples $(\theta,S,F)$.

Comment: You might search for situations where the *logit* of the parameter has a given distribution.  For the small values you report, the logit and log are nearly the same.  This would point you towards Bayes versions of logistic regression.

Comment: How do you get your large dataset of triples ? What distribution is $\theta$ drawn from ? (I assume you then draw (S,F) from a binomial distribution with that value of $\theta$)

Comment: @gazza89: to be clear I derive $\theta$ from $S,F$ via its empirical estimate

Comment: then how are you getting S and F? What are they sampled from ?

Comment: @gazza89: It's from a dataset I have, where each row records a single success or failure. I can cheat by splitting the dataset into pieces, because with full data, I have good confidence on the empirical value of $\theta$, but with just part, then there's less confidence, hence the need for a prior.

Comment: yeah, I still definitely don't understand what you're doing. You want to use half of your data to construct a prior for which to perform inference using the second half as data?